# Hover при наведении

Tags: html, css, hover

Имеем такой код:

```css
.pre p {
  width: 301px;
  height: 226px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #000000;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50.4%;
  left: 50.0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.pre p:hover,
img:hover + p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pre .col-md-4 > div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="pitr">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="comf">
      <img src="images/solo9.jpg">
      <p>Рапапам</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. при наведении на картинку появляется текст на белом фоне. Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке кода снизу картинки был текст, а при наведении появлялся мой фрагмент кода?

Comment: Немного подформатировал ваш код, удалил лишнее. 1) Можете загрузить сюда картинку и добавить ссылку в сниппет? То есть ваша картинка не загружается. 2) Классов `.pre` и элементов `p` в HTML нет, то есть ваш CSS очень слабо соотносится с HTML.

Answer (score 1):

но можно сделать плавнее с помощью JQuery

```css
.pre p {
  width: 301px;
  height: 226px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #000000;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50.4%;
  left: 50.0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.pre p:hover,
img:hover + p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pre .col-md-4 > div {
  position: relative;
}
.hover-hide,
.after-hover {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }
 .comf .after-hover
{
  display: none;
}

.comf:hover .hover-hide {
  display: none;
}
.comf:hover .after-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pitr">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="comf">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg">
      <p class="hover-hide">Рапапам</p>
      <p class="after-hover">Text after hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```